# Conjugacy classes of a subgroup of index 2.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$  and $K$ a conjugacy class of $G.$

How can one show that $K \cap H$ is either empty, a conjugacy class of $H$ or is split into two conjugacy classes of $H$ of equal order?

In particular why is it that $K \cap H$ gets split if and only if some $k \in K$ commutes with some $g \not \in H$?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says that the set of elements commuting with $x$ is a subgroup whose index is the size of the conjugacy class of $x$?

Comment: @Seth, if that's not a rhetorical question, look at the conjugacy class of $(123)$ in $S_4$ and in the index-2 subgroup, $A_4$.

Comment: First look at $h^{-1}(K \cap H)h$ for $h \in H.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am good at misreading things.  I read conjugacy class of $G$ when it said conjugacy class of $H$...

Comment: Note that there is (apparently) no assumption here that $G$ is a finite group, which means you have to be more careful, but the question is still correct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No I don't know that theorem. How can it be applied in this case?

Comment: The first step is to show is that either $K \subseteq H$ or $K \subseteq G \setminus H$. Can you prove that?

Comment: Let $A$ be the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. Then the centralizer of $g$ in $H$ is $A\cap H$. If $A\subseteq H$, then the size of $A\cap H$ is the size of $A$. What if $A$ is not a subset of $H$? How big is $A\cap H$ then?

Comment: The final statement is wrong; consider the conjugacy class of $3$-cycles in $S_3$ which splits in two classes in the (Abelian) subgroup $A_3$, yet no $3$-cycle commutes with any odd permutation (here: transposition).

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Is there a simple way to see the index of $A\cap H$ in $H$?

Comment: @Eric, it's probably better to post your question as a new question, rather than as a comment on a very old question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I denote conjugation by a dot: $g\cdot x$ means $gxg^{-1}$.

Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ with Abelian quotient, all orbits $H\cdot x$ in $G$ under conjugation by $H$ are contained in one of the (two) cosets in $G/H$. Now if $g_1\in G-H$ is arbitrary, it is easily seen that any conjugacy class $K=G\cdot x$ is given by $K= H\cdot x\cup H\cdot(g_1\cdot x)$, where the two orbits being united are either disjoint or equal. Depending on the number of *distinct* orbits among $H\cdot x$ and $H\cdot(g_1\cdot x)$ that lie inside $$g_1\in G-H$H$, which number can be $0$, $1$, or $2$, the intersection $K\cap H$ consists of $0$, $1$, or $2$ conjugacy classes in$~H$. (Also the number is $0$ iff $x\notin H$.)
When there are two of them, conjugation by $g_1$ defines a bijection between those two conjugacy classes.

As for the final statement, it should read "$K \cap H$ is a $H$-conjugacy class (so it *does not get split*) if and only if $K\subseteq H$ and some $k\in K$ commutes with some $g \notin H$". The condition that $k\in K\cap H$ commutes with $g \notin H$ means that for some $g_1\in G-H$ one has $H\cdot k=H\cdot(g_1\cdot k)$: if the condition holds, one can take $g_1=g$; conversely if $h\cdot k=g_1\cdot k$ then $h^{-1}g_1\notin H$ commutes with $k$. So in this case the union above is really just one $H$-orbit. Then either $K\cap H=\emptyset$ or $K\cap H=K$. In fact when $K\cap H=\emptyset$ we are always in this situation (since one can take $g=k$) but when $K\subseteq H$ it depends. The above classification is a bit misleading; more explicitely one of the following happens:

1. $K\cap H=\emptyset$ and $K$ is one $H$-conjugation orbit (but not of course a conjugation class of$~H$).
2. $K\subseteq H$ and some $k\in K$ commutes with some $g\notin H$; then $K$ is a single $H$ conjugation class.
3. $K\subseteq H$ but no $k\in K$ commutes with any $g\notin H$; then $K$ splits into two $H$ conjugation classes.

Comment: Hm.. what exactly do you mean by "all orbits of H\cdot x$ under conjugation with $H$?

Comment: @Jernej: Well, $H$ acts on $G$ by conjugation: $h\cdot g=hgh^{-1}$. So the orbits of $H$ in $G$ under this (conjugation) action are the sets of the form $H\cdot g=\{\,hgh^{-1}\mid h\in H\,\}$, where $g\in G$ is fixed. They are actually conjugacy classes in $H$ if (and only if) $g\in H$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Somehow I downvoted your question and I cannot upvote unless you make an edit to this post. Hence could you make a minor change so that I can correct the vote?

Comment: @Jernej: I've made a small change.